# Spring data JPA compatibility issue: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext'

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When I've adapted 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:2.0.1.RELEASE'

As a result,

Spring Data JPA was upgraded to 1.9.2.RELEASE from 1.4.3.RELEASE

and Spring Data Common was upgraded to 1.11.2.RELEASE from 1.6.3.RELEASE

Now, the JBoss EAP 6.2 raised the following complain during deployment

```
    Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

    Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Set]: : No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [collection of javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; 

   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] found for dependency [collection of javax.persistence.EntityManager]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**Build Environment**

---

### Gradle 2.9

Build time:   2015-11-17 07:02:17 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b463d7980c40d44c4657dc80025275b84a29e31f

Groovy:       2.4.4

Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013

JVM:          1.7.0_60-ea (Oracle Corporation 24.60-b09)

OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show the code for your `jpaContext` bean

Comment: @RobertNiestroj, I have not defined jpaContext anywhere.  I have <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/pu/pc" />

Comment: @RobertNiestroj, Is it similar to https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/DATAJPA-813/DATAJPA-813.html ?