# Spring Boot: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to do a basic CRUD API using Spring Boot, Hibernate, and MySQL. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial). I am running into this:

`UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [java.util.Set] found for dependency [java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>]`.

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.0.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- I added the two above dependencies but the error is still there. -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here's my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todo" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="pass" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.example.models.Todo</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="todoDAO" class="com.example.models.TodoDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="todoService" class="com.example.services.TodoServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="todoDAO" ref="todoDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

I saw this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126880/spring-data-jpa-compatibility-issue-error-creating-bean-with-name-jpacontext) but it didn't help much since it has no answer. My understanding is that I am using the Hibernate API to persist objects with JPA annotations. Do I need to add any JPA dependencies in my `pom.xml`? I am really confused.

Any and all help would be very much appreciated! I just want to have a simply CRUD API setup and I thought the tutorial I'm following is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: If you're using Spring Boot, you really shouldn't be using a big external configuration file like that. Kill the whole thing and replace it with `application.properties`.

Comment: What two lines would you be talking about? I'm a beginner to Spring so I have no experience configuring projects.

Comment: Use Spring Boot application properties to autoconfigure the entire Hibernate setup. [Here's a good intro.](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: I saw that one before! I'm trying to remove the xml bulk and I'm getting a different error this time:
https://gist.github.com/Sticksword/c6fce2162fd4de1e4587b80508ad6bba

Comment: Why are you using Spring Boot... As you are trying very hard not to. For starters clean up your pom and add the actual stacktrace instead of a snippet. Also a `SessionFactory` isn't a `EntityManagerFactory`. Use the JPA api instead of plain hibernate to write your daos.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you add the Maven compiler plugin to the POM?  Something like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <source>${java.version}</source>
            <target>${java.version}</target>
            <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
            <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
            <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I'm still getting a Maven build error unfortunately :/ I'll poke around with settings and let you know if anything changes.

Comment: It was only a wild guess, sorry about that.  Can you post the entire startup log file, perhaps as a gist on gist.github.com?  Perhaps an error earlier in the log file is showing why it could not create the entity manager.

Comment: Have you defined a persistence unit manager, via a persistence.xml or through annotations somehow?  I don't see one in your application context.  In my project I use Spring's persistence unit support, via `org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager` class.

Comment: I don't know what a persistence unit manager is. I used Hibernate API with JPA annotations to persist objects. Also, I'll post the gist in a minute

Comment: I uploaded the Maven build error stack here:
https://gist.github.com/Sticksword/f3cec4379934b016a0e0135cd9b1e69d